# replace a healthy drive in Raid5 on NAS

Tags: network-attached-storage, raid5

Good day!

I have a 4 disk Iomega NAS. The config is:

4x2TB RAID5, 4.4 allocated, 2.3TB used, and i kept 1TB as available, but not allocated.

Nothing has failed, but while 3 disks are 7200 rpm and are almost the same, the fourth one is 5400 and is not quite the same, despite the same size. I want to replace it with the one similar to the other three (same manufacturer, speed etc). Can I just pull the odd one out and plug a fresh one in? Or there is more to it?

Comment: Other than waiting hours if not a day or two with a degraded RAID, I'd say that's all there is to it.

Comment: Yes. No. Nothing more to add.

Comment: have a working backup?

Comment: I think a backup would be a good idea, it'd be terrible if you pulled a good drive and another failed while it was rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

It worked. Thanks to all the comments. However, after I pulled my drive I received Drive 3 is Missing, which stayed the same even after I plugged the new one in. I replugged the old one, it started rebuilding data protection. Then I unplugged it and replugged the new one again. Same thing: drive 3 is missing. Then I slid it out and shoved it in brutally. Then I received the "overwrite authorization", which I gave and the rebuilding started and ended in several hours...